# How to store selected values from UI to an array in controller?

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I am trying to retrieve the list of grades for each subject in a angularjs controller to pass it to my REST API. I tested the code using a string of comma separated grades and it works well, now I am looking get the grades dynamically from user. Currently I'm only accepting comma separated grades in my API. And How can I iterate to generate all list of subjects with grade options dynamically  in angular?

```
    $http.jsonp("http://localhost/api/cgpa/"+ "a1,a2,e1,c2,e1,c1" +"?callback=JSON_CALLBACK") // callback is necessary for jsonp to initiate .sucess function
    .success(function(data, status, headers, config) {
        $scope.data = 'Your CGPA is ' + data.cgpa;
    })
    .error(function(){
        $scope.data = 'Error';
    });
```

[image: Calculator]

Also please suggest me If I can achieve this kind of feature through angularjs to add unlimited number of subjects through "Add Subject" button?

[image: Add item]

Comment: I know i asked too much in a single question but if you can provide the some links I can refer to, it would be awesome. I'm new to angular and not familiar with the terms to search for.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you have a few options:

1) Use a function in ng-repeat to register "clicked" elements:

```js
app.controller('AppCtrl', ['$scope', 'yourService', function($scope, yourService){ 
  $scope.selected = [];

  yourService.fetch(function(items){
    $scope.items = items;
  });

  $scope.select = function(item){
    var index;
    if ((index = $scope.selected.indexOf(item)) !== -1){
      $scope.selected.splice(index, 1); // remove already existing, aka toggle
    } else {
      $scope.selected.push(item);
    }
  }

  $scope.isSelected = function(item){
     return $scope.selected.indexOf(item) > -1;
  }

  $scope.calculate = function(){
    var items = [];
    for(var i = 0, len = $scope.selected.length; i < len; i++){
      items.push($scope.selected[i].value);
    }
    yourService.jsonp(items.join(','));
  }
});
```

```html
<div ng-repeat="item in items">
  <div ng-click="select(item)" ng-class="{'isSelected':isSelected(item)}">{{ your item data }}</div>
</div>
```

2) Put a "state" on each of your items

```js
app.controller('AppCtrl', ['$scope', 'yourService', function($scope, yourService){ 
  yourService.fetch(function(items){
    for(var i = 0, len = items.length; i < len; i++){
      items[i].selected = false;
    }
    $scope.items = items;
  });

  $scope.calculate = function(){
    var items = [];
    for(var i = 0, len = $scope.items.length; i < len; i++){
      if ($scope.items[i].selected) {
        items.push($scope.items[i].value); // this could be done with .reduce or .map, but it's not cross-browser 
      }
    }
    yourService.jsonp(items.join(','));
  }
});
```

```html
<div ng-repeat="item in items">
  <div ng-click="item.selected=!item.selected" ng-class="{'isSelected':item.selected}">{{ your item data }}</div>
</div>
```

3) You could (and should) centralize all the selecting / deselecting / submitting data in your service instead of putting it all in your controller scope, that way you can reuse the code and is usually good practice

4) Another way is to create a isolated scope directive for each of your buttons, but I think it's overkill for what you are trying to accomplish

Basically your UI will always reflect your data, and not the other way around.